# How to control CMake compiler command to remove"-c" option before the input file

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, build, ninja

I'm trying to remove the "-c" option when calling my compiler when building C-files. At the moment, I'm using the Ninja generator, but I would say it would be similar with Make.

Here's the Ninja rules which are generated by my CMake project:

```
#############################################
# Rule for compiling C files.

rule C_COMPILER__XXXX_
  depfile = $DEP_FILE
  deps = gcc
  command = gcc.exe $DEFINES $INCLUDES $FLAGS -MD -MT $out -MF $DEP_FILE -o $out -c $in
  description = Building C object $out


#############################################
```

I need to remove the "-c" before specifying the Input File to be compiled. The above example uses GCC, but my "real" compiler does not support the -c option.

Any ideas ? I tried to play with the Compile Options but no success - and I did not find a way to have 100% control over the command which is used to compile.

The only thing I found was to use a "custom command".

Comment: `Any ideas ?`? If you use your own compiler with custom semantics, then write configuration for that compiler. How are you setting your compiler? Did you write your compiler detection file and specific configuration? Please show your CMakeLists.txt. Please create an [MCVE]. `I did not find a way to have 100% control` Setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT` variable from within `Compiler/your_compiler.cmake` should work.

Comment: [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html?highlight=compile_object) and [IAR.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake#L47) has a nice example.

Comment: Or you could add and ignore the `-c` option, as some command does for compatibility with mainstream syntax. Or create a command wrapper that remove `-c`.

Comment: I'm using the Tasking compiler for Infineon Aurix TriCore. 

"How are you setting your compiler" For now setting the variable "CMAKE_C_COMPILER" to the compiler executable. Maybe later with the "CC" env var.

"Setting CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT variable from within Compiler/your_compiler.cmake should work" Thanks for that, I think that's exactly what I want to do. 

I'll try to create my own Tasking.cmake, based on the one for IAR that you mentioned. Thanks again.